# I want to sell most of the shares of a company. Can I buy them back later without tax consequences or a wash tax?

Tags: stocks

If I sell most of the shares of a company I own, and then buy them back within the month is that a wash sale?  Can I buy the shares back without a tax penalty?

Comment: You have to specify your jurisdiction. Are you in the US?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, a wash sale occurs if  you execute a closing trade for a loss and within 30 days before or after  realizing the loss, you buy (or sell) a “substantially identical” stock,  security, or option contract.

If you sell your shares for a gain, you may be liable for taxes.  If you sell them for a loss, you may be able to  deduct the loss and reduce your taxes.  If you violate the 60 day window after a loss, some or all of that loss might be  deferred until the shares in the additional purchase are disposed of.